# How do i use the for loop for a specified range while using maps in c++

Tags: c++

I want to use the `for` loops with iterators while using maps and want to run it for a specified range not from `begin()` end `end()`. I would want to use it for a range like from 3rd element to 5th element

Comment: So you know what you want to do, where's the problem? Where is the code that's causing an issue?

Comment: Use `std::next` to advance the `begin` iterator.

Comment: You know those "old" examples of `for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)`? You can in fact use other iterator values besides `begin` and `end`, if you have them.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Rotem can you give and example

Comment: 3rd element: `std::next(map.begin(), 2)`

Comment: Also, check the lookup functions [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for ways to get iterators to elements of specific values.

Comment: 5th element `std::next(map.begin(), 4)`

Comment: I feel like you're really looking for [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) and [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound)

Answer (score 6):

> I would want to use it for a range like from 3rd element to 5th
>   element

Since `std::map`'s iterator is not a `RandomAccessIterator`, but only a `BidirectionalIterator` (you cannot write `.begin() + 3`), you can use `std::next` for this purpose:

```
for (auto it = std::next(m.begin(), 2); it != std::next(m.begin(), 5); ++it)
{
  // ...
}
```

---

And remember - check your ranges to ensure, that you iterate over a valid scope.

Comment: Worth saving the value of `std::next(m.begin(), 5);` instead of recalculating it each time round the loop

Comment: I wonder, would there be gains in storing the end condition iterator or would compilers be aware enough to optimize the `std::next` away if the map is not modified withing the loop?

Comment: I doubt compilers would be aware enough.

Comment: It's important to note that if the map doesn't have at least 5 elements, this will result in undefined behavior. Depending on OP's circumstances, a size check or an `assert` statement might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be pretty optimal and safe for corner cases:

```
int count = 0;
for( auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it ) {
    if( ++count <= 3 ) continue;
    if( count > 5 ) break;
    // use iterator
}
```

but the fact you are iterating an `std::map` this way shows most probably you are using a wrong container (or your logic for 3rd to 5th element is wrong)

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is possible i m not implementing it anywhere✌

Comment: @Rahulmalawadkar everything is possible, question is what is the price.